# VLOOKUP or VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I was just wondering if anyone could help me with this please?

[image]

I am trying to look up information in the same/another spreadsheets.

Below where there's a dropdown menu, I would like to select a CREW name and output the information from A:D Column.

I have tried VLOOKUP but it when I type in the CREW name it would result in error, but when I type in the "Day" it will result in copying the entire row.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Check out the FILTER function if you have a recent version of Excel. No need for VBA.

Comment: @CLR I am try the FILTER option but it can only filter a single "CREW" column not all.

Comment: To move between sheets easily, I suggest index() with match(). Just make sure that the number of items in index is matched with the number in match().

Comment: Create a new column, containing a concatenation of all the crew fields, space or comma separated - and then apply the filter to that column using *contains*.

Comment: @CLR that doesn't work either

Comment: @SolarMike is it possible to do with text?

Comment: @TK4795 As [the help file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) helpfully mentions, you can Add or Multiply Filter Conditions to combine them, because `TRUE` and `FALSE` can be treated as `1` and `0`.  i.e. `FILTER(.., ($Q$1:$Q$7=$F$10)+($R$1:$R$7=$F$10)..+($Z$1:$Z$7=$F$10), ..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new column in column AB. Give it any name you like.

Use the formula `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Q2:AA2)` in AB2, and copy the formula down.

Then, in cell A13 or thereabouts, enter the following formula:

```
=FILTER(A1:D7,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F10,AB1:AB7)),"No results")
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This formular work perfectly, thank you so much.